# php artisan commands returning output by attaching dot(.) symbol in first line

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

When I run an artisan command like `php artisan --version`, It gives output by attaching '.'(dot) in the first line like `.Laravel Framework 9.5.1`

Due to this in each js file, there is '.' in the first line which shows an error in console.

[[image: this image attaching '.' in each output1]

[image: correct output]

So, how I can solve the problem?

Comment: sounds like a bug that should be reported as an issue

Comment: @IGP I started a discussion on Github - https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/41547

Comment: I tried to replicate in my project with exact same version and this is not happening to me. I think could me a terminal issue instead.

Comment: @Guille I don't think that's a terminal issue because I used the same terminal for two different projects and run command one is working fine another attaching dot in its output.

Comment: Did you make changes inside your artisan file inside your root directory by mistake?

Comment: @gguney as you said, I copied the whole code from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/artisan for artisan.php but got the same error.